# How to calculate the expected cost of an outcome?

Tags: probability

Suppose I am going to buy many \$100 lotteries. 
Each have 20% chance to win a special item, and 80% chance to get a consolation prize that is $30.

Now I am going to win the special item no matter how much I spent.
So how much is the expected cost of the special item?

I have checked the expected cost formula without consolation prize is 
100/20% = \$500
But what if it has consolation prize?

Comment: Each round you lose costs you $70$ rather than $100$ so it's just $70\times 5=350.$ It would be a bit trickier if you only got the consolation prize a certain percentage of the times you lose.

Comment: Looking at the answer below, the correct answer is indeed $\$380$. I forgot that on the last round you don't get the $\$30$ back. (And the answer below shows how to do the trickier case.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L_i$ be the iid RV representing the cost of the $i$th failure. Let $N$ be the RV number of losses before winning, so $N\sim\text{Geom}(p)$, which is a stopping time for our process. Then, the total expected loss is:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^N L_i\right] = \mathbb{E}[N]\mathbb{E}[L_i]
$$
by Wald's identity.

For example, if you lose $L_i=100$ each time (i.e. $L_i$ is not random) with success probability $p=0.2$, we have $\mathbb{E}[N]=1/p=5$ so total loss is $500$.

Now suppose there is a consolation prize worth $30$, but no monetary award for winning.
So, if you lose $L_i=70$ each time you dont get the prize, and there is success probability $p=0.2$, we get:
$$
\text{Expected Cost} = \mathbb{E}[N]\mathbb{E}[L_i] 
= \frac{1}{p}[(100p)+70(1-p)] = 5[0.2(100)+0.8(70)]=380
$$
Basically this means you can expect 4 losses (losing $70$ each) and 1 win (costing $100$).